# Случайно установил загрузчик Ubuntu поверх загрузчика Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub

При установке Ubuntu с дуру поставил ее загрузчик в раздел, где располагается загрузчик Windows. В итоге, когда при загрузке системы появляется окно выбора операционной системы, я могу выбрать и загрузить Ubuntu, но при выборе Windows я снова попадаю на окно выбора. Другими словами, попадаю в бесконечный цикл, выход из которого - выбор в качестве цели Ubuntu.

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы все заработало должным образом?

Само собой, хотелось бы краткую и емкую инструкцию или довольно содержательную наводку. Не хотелось бы закапываться в эту тему на несколько дней.

Comment: боюсь, Вы снесли Windows. полностью.

Comment: Я уверен, что проблема решаема. Абсурдно думать, что это не так. Раздел загрузчика является слабо редактируемым, чисто системным и изолированным местом, которое, вероятно, имеет только одно состояние. Думаю, можно банально перезаписать весь раздел на необходимое состояние и уверен, что есть готовые решения для этого. Это то, что мне подсказывает здравый смысл. Другое дело, что я не имею необходимых навыков и знаний.

Comment: нынче (в эпоху uefi) все загрузчкики складируются в отдельном небольшом разделе блочного устройства. судя по приведённой информации, с этим-то разделом всё в порядке. а вот как обстоят дела с разделом(-ами), содержащими ms/windows, из вопроса не ясно. KoVadim выдвинул гипотезу, что этих разделов уже нет. давайте проверим эту гипотезу. загрузитесь и выполните команду `$ sudo fdisk -l`, а вывод её (как текст) приложите к вопросу (нажав [edit]).

Comment: Я уже восстановил загрузчик, спасибо за отклик. Подробности напишу в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знал как это работает в точности, но я знал, что для загрузчиков выделен отдельный раздел и он никак не связан с основными разделами на которых стоят операционные системы. Этот факт придал мне смелости в дальнейших действиях и уверенность в том, что остальные разделы я не испорчу. В крайнем случае, все файлы можно было восстановить из загрузочной флешки.

Так как основная проблема заключалась в загрузке windows, а для меня эта система была приоритетной, то я решил восстановить ее загрузчик в первую очередь. Даже если это в итоге сломало бы сам загрузчик ubuntu (его я бы уже пытался восстановить потом, было предположение, что это проще сделать). Поэтому я начал искать методы восстановления загрузчика windows. И, о боги, практически сразу нашел ответ в следующем [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWsFAyluJ0U).

В видео описаны три способа, но в моем случае помог именно последний из них. Если вкратце, то был проделан следующий порядок действий (описал то, как я понял процесс):

1. Создаем загрузочные файлы
2. Форматируем загрузочный раздел (на этом этапе я смирился с потерей загрузчика ubuntu)
3. Копируем созданные загрузочные файлы в пустой загрузочный раздел.
4. Перезагружаемся и все починилось

Вопреки моим ожиданиям Ubuntu осталась на месте. Вероятно, как и отметил aleksandr barakin, загрузчик ubuntu (или ссылка на него) сложился в специальный раздел до которого мои руки не дотянулись. А я старался, во время первой попытки даже отформатировал не тот раздел (думаю, то был раздел восстановления windows, но хер с ним).